# How to access the value of an object returned from an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API that I'm attempting to filter out every title with a rating of 'Rx'.

The returned json data is stored within a variable called **dataItems**.

Example: If I want to return the rating for the first object, I'd do **dataItems[0].rated**

My attempt to filter out anything rated "Rx" is the following.

```
class AnimeCard extends Component {
  render() {
    const { dataItems } = this.props
    console.log(dataItems)

    return (
      <AnimeCardWrapper>
        {dataItems.filter(item => item !== item.rated['Rx']).map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <AnimeCardItem>
              <PosterImg src={item.image_url} alt="poster" />
              <CardTitle key={index}>{item.title}</CardTitle>
              <p>{item.score}</p>
              <p>{item.rated}</p>
            </AnimeCardItem>
          )
        })}
      </AnimeCardWrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

Doing so gives me the following error: **"TypeError: item.rated is null"**

I've attempted to pull out the string "Rx" into a variable and then do **rated[rxVariable]**, but I still receive the same error.

I also attempted to use Object.values(), but I still had no luck. I'm sure there's something I'm overlooking.

Just to be clear, I'd like to display every item **except** those with rated: "Rx"

Comment: Probably want `.filter(item =>  item.rated !== 'Rx')`. A sample of data would help

Comment: @charlietfl That solved my problem. I'll go scream into a corner as I've been trying to figure this out for over an hour now lol THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should change the line `dataItems.filter(item => item !== item.rated['Rx']` to `dataItems.filter(item => item.rated !== 'Rx'`